# ctypes doesn't find fink-installed libraries in /sw/lib

Tags: python, ctypes, fink

`ctypes` isn't finding libraries installed via fink, which live under `/sw/lib/`, unless I explicitly give the full path to the libraries

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.CDLL('libgoffice-0.8.dylib')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libgoffice-0.8.dylib, 6): image not found
>>> ctypes.CDLL('/sw/lib/libgoffice-0.8.dylib')
<CDLL '/sw/lib/libgoffice-0.8.dylib', handle 336500 at 2b10b0>
>>>
```

Compilation against these libraries with `gcc`, however, works fine; they are always found. Why isn't `ctypes` locating these libraries, and what can I do to make it locate them?

This is on OS X 10.6.8 with fink-installed Python 2.7 under `/sw/bin/python2.7`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that fink never sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. `ctypes` uses `dlopen()` which will not search in `/sw/lib` by default. From the `dlopen` man page:

> dlopen() searches for a compatible Mach-O file in the directories speci-
>   fied by a set of environment variables and the process's current working
>   directory.  When set, the environment variables must contain a colon-sep-
>   arated list of directory paths, which can be absolute or relative to the
>   current working directory. The environment variables are LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
>   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.  The first two vari-
>   ables have no default value. The default value of DYLD_FALL-
>   BACK_LIBRARY_PATH is $HOME/lib;/usr/local/lib;/usr/lib.  dlopen()
>   searches the directories specified in the environment variables in the
>   order they are listed.

So the solution seems to be to put in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sw/lib:"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

It also seems that fink installs some libraries in subdirectories under `/sw/lib`, such as `/sw/lib/mysql`. In these cases, you will have to explicitly include those, as well, because it seems like the `dlopen()` does not recursively search the paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In the case of MySQL, you would need to add that in the path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sw/lib:/sw/lib/mysql:"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```